# What is $P(X<Y)$ when $X,Y$ represent a random sample from two distributions.

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-distributions, self-learning

> The income of people in two cities is represented by two Pareto-type pdfs:
>   $$f(x)=\frac{2}{x^3},1<x<\infty,g(y)=\frac{3}{y^4},1<y<\infty$$
>   One person is selected at random from each city. Let $X$ and $Y$ be their respective incomes. Compute $P(X<Y)$.

It makes sense to me that this would be the integral of $f(x)$ when it is less than $f(y)$ but I am not sure how to set this up. Perhaps there is a better way altogether? Can I have a hint?

Comment: Whether $f(x)$ is less than $f(y)$ is not the question; rather it is wether $x$ is less than $y$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming $X$, $Y$ are independent, the desired probability is given by $$\Pr[X < Y] = \int_{x=1}^\infty \int_{y=1}^\infty \mathbb{1}(x < y) f_{X,Y}(x,y) \, dy \, dx = \int_{x=1}^\infty \int_{y=x}^\infty f_X(x)f_Y(y) \ dy \, dx $$ where $$\mathbb{1}(x < y) = \begin{cases} 1, & x < y \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}$$

Comment: That's correct. [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Int%5bInt%5b2%2fx%5e3+3%2fy%5e4%2c+%7by%2cx%2cInf%7d%5d%2c+%7bx%2c1%2cInf%7d%5d) gives this probability equal to 40%.

Answer (score 0):

By the partition theorem;

$$\mathbb{P}(X < Y) = \int_Y \mathbb{P}(X < Y \mid Y = y)g(y)~dy$$

Comment: What does $y$ equal in this case?

Comment: $y$ is some arbitrary value of $Y$. You are partitioning over every value that $Y$ can take, so the integral should go from $y = 1$ to $y = \infty$.

Comment: I don't understand how to resolve $\mathbb{P}(X < Y | Y = y)$.

Comment: Ok, so $\mathbb{P}(X < Y | Y = y)$ is equivalent to $\mathbb{P}(X < y)$, where y is just some arbitrary value. It's just a number.